# Replace values in entire data frame with column values in R

Tags: r, replace

I did some search but cannot find an obvious answer of this question so hopefully it's not a duplicated question. I have a data frame looks like this:

```
X1 X2 V1 V2 V3 ... Vn
A  B  0  1  2      1
B  C  1  0  1      0
A  C  2  1  0      1
```

What I want to achieve is to replace V1 to Vn values to the "dosage" of X2. So for **row 1** (each row may have different values of X1 and X2),

- if the value is 0, I want to replace it to AA;
- if the value is 1, I want to replace it to AB;
- if the value is 2, I want to replace it to BB;

The expected outcome is:

```
X1 X2 V1 V2 V3 ... Vn
A  B  AA AB BB     AB
B  C  BC BB BC     BB
A  C  CC AC AA     AC
```

Here is the sample data frame:

```
df=data.frame(X1=c("A","B","A"),
              X2=c("B","C","C"),
              V1=c(0,1,2),
              V2=c(1,0,1),
              V3=c(2,1,0))
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is inspired from @Matt's answer. We can use `mutate_at` with `paste0` to achieve this task.

```
## Load packages
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-X1, -X2), .funs = list(
    ~case_when(
      . == 0            ~paste0(X1, X1),
      . == 1            ~paste0(X1, X2),
      . == 2            ~paste0(X2, X2),
      TRUE              ~NA_character_
    )
  ))
dat2
#   X1 X2 V1 V2 V3 Vn
# 1  A  B AA AB BB AB
# 2  B  C BC BB BC BB
# 3  A  C CC AC AA AC
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "X1 X2 V1 V2 V3 Vn
A  B  0  1  2  1
B  C  1  0  1  0
A  C  2  1  0  1 ",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Excellent solution. But I don't understand the use of ~ in front of case_when and paste. I tried to see an example but couldn't spot any other thread. Can you help explain or point to a thread. Thanks.

Comment: I understand the ~ in front of paste0. I just need help understanding the ~ in front of case_when.

Comment: @ShanR Please see this page (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html). There is an example such as `starwars %>% mutate_at(c("height", "mass"), ~scale2(., na.rm = TRUE))`. This is similar to the syntax in the `purrr` package.

Answer (score 3):

With your actual `df` you can replace `V1:V3` with `V1:Vn`.

Using your reprex, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)


df %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(V1:V3),
    funs(case_when(
      . == 0 ~ "AA",
      . == 1 ~ "AB",
      . == 2 ~ "BB"
    ))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response but the values of X1 and X2 for each row are not always the same.

Comment: Ah sorry! Didn't notice that. Looks like @www took care of it though!

Comment: It is still a brilliant solution @Matt. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It not an elegant solution but for the sake of completeness: just nest two for-loops

```r
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  for (j in 3:dim(df)[2]){
    if (df[i,j] == 0){
      df[i,j] <- paste0(df[i,1], df[i,1])
    } else if (df[i,j] == 1) {
      df[i,j] <- paste0(df[i,1], df[i,2])
    } else if (df[i,j] == 2) {
      df[i,j] <- paste0(df[i,2], df[i,2])
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks much, this works but I have a large data set and @www's answer perform a lot faster. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Yes, usally for-loops aren't a good way to get the job done, but still it's a possible solution. I prefer Matt's and www's solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `spread` and `gather`

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(X1=c("A","B","A"),
              X2=c("B","C","C"),
              V1=c(0,1,2),
              V2=c(1,0,1),
              V3=c(2,1,0))
```

Capture your from:to translation

```
transl <- tibble(DOSE = c(0,1,2),
                 OUTCOME = c("AA", "AB", "AC"))
```

Then `Gather` your values into long form

```
longTbl <- df %>% 
  gather(key = "TheV", value = "DOSE", na.rm = TRUE,starts_with("V")) %>% 
  left_join(transl, by = "DOSE") %>% 
  select(- DOSE)


# A tibble: 9 x 4
  X1    X2    TheV  OUTCOME
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 A     B     V1    AA     
2 B     C     V1    AB     
3 A     C     V1    AC     
4 A     B     V2    AB     
5 B     C     V2    AA     
6 A     C     V2    AB     
7 A     B     V3    AC     
8 B     C     V3    AB     
9 A     C     V3    AA
```

You might be better leaving it there.  But we can pivot it back with `spread`.

```
widTbl <- longTbl %>% 
  spread(TheV, OUTCOME )
widTbl

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  X1    X2    V1    V2    V3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     B     AA    AB    AC   
2 A     C     AC    AB    AA   
3 B     C     AB    AA    AB
```

And Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thanks much. Sorry I did some clarification from my original post. Each row may have have different value of X1 and X2 and the replacement should only based on the value within the same row.